# Can we get a better way to fix our reviewing mistakes?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, review-suspension

Yesterday I missclicked on https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26908966 to Requires Editting, so I immediately went to the question and flagged it as I should have done. Today I got a 3 day suspension for not following the triage rules.

Was there a better way to handle situation like this for me ? If not isn't there a better way of handling these situations from a site perspective ?

Comment: Ideally you should take your time, if you're missclicking then chances are you're not taking your time and/or not paying enough attention

Comment: If you immediately flagged the question for closure, I'm sure a mod will oblige and lift the suspension.